# Сравнение двух массивов и замена одинаковых значений

Tags: php, массивы

Необходимо сравнить 2 массива, и заменить элементы, которые присутствуют во 2-ом нулями.

Пример двух массивов:

```
['0' => '1', '1' => '2', '2' => '3', '3' => '4']
['0' => '3', '1' => '1']
```

Как получить из этих двух массивов следующий?

```
['0' => '0', '1' = '2', '2' => '0', '3' => '4']
```

Comment: @Let'ssayPie, с какой целью строковые значения в вопросе были заменены числовыми?

Comment: @Qwertiy, изначально делал с ними, после тестировал с числами, и забыл вернуть к прежнему виду, благодарю за правку..

Answer (score 1):

```
$array1 = ['0' => '1', '1' => '2', '2' => '3', '3' => '4'];
$array2 = ['0' => '3', '1' => '1'];

foreach ($array1 as $k => $v) {
    if (in_array($v, $array2)) $array1[$k] = 0;
}

print_r($array1);
```

https://3v4l.org/k9DJU

Comment: Производительность так себе, но работать должно.Вопросу вроде соответствует.

Comment: @Qwertiy, могу поинтересоваться, а где тут производительность хромает?)

Comment: Асимптотика получается квадратичная - при больших массивах может быть плохо. Если использовать словарь, то можно сделать с линейной.